# Asp.net url rewriting, without CNAME

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have to use URL filtering in one of my sites.
Take for example the site:
*http://default.net*
and I wish I could add something to the URL and filter based on that.
*http://foo.default.net*
In writing this I would like to retrieve the "**foo**" and can use it.
This URL filtering should be done without CNAME (ie dynamic).

PS: Note that I do not want *http://default.net/foo* but *http://foo.default.net*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-domain-routing.aspx) which illustrates how you could define domain routes.